# Extending docker image

Tags: docker, docker-image

I want to extend the existing redis:6.0-alpine image from docker-hub and want to add my configuration file in the container.

For that I've created this dockerfile

```
FROM redis:6.0-alpine

WORKDIR .
COPY redis.master.conf ./config/redis.conf
```

but when building a container from this image, there is nothing copyed at the specified location.

Setup:

1. wsl2 (ubuntu 18.04 distro)
2. windows 10
3. docker-for-windows (v20.10.2)

Some help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `WORKDIR` is set to `.` in your dockerfile, which means current working directory. If you look at the official [dockerfile of redis:6.0-alpine](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/master/6.0/alpine/Dockerfile#L96), the `WORKDIR` is set to `/data`.

Hence according to your dockerfile, you are copying the `redis.master.conf` file to `./` which means `/data`. Please check your file at `/data/etc/redis.conf`. I tried this at my end and can confirm this behavior.

If you want to copy it at `/etc/redis.conf` then remove `./` before `/etc`.

Comment: sorry, are you confirming that it works or that it does not work ?

Comment: if you want to copy it at `/etc/redis.conf` then remove `./` before `/etc`.

Comment: @boris it's funny because this is exactly the same answer I told you 2h earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

Just tested myself, and it's copied without issues.

Where are you trying to look for the file? Notice the entry directory of this image is not `/`, it's `/data`, hence your file is on `/data/etc/redis.conf`

Comment: I've searched in data/ and etc/. It's not there, I've update the question providing local setup information

Comment: no, your assumption is not correct. What you are seeing is actaully the predefined config file. If you would create a docker container using redis:latest and ssh into it, go to data/etc/. you would see the redis.conf file. I've tested this. I've changed my redis.conf file and the changes do not take effect.

Comment: @boris I didn't name the file redis.conf for testing :)